# Anyone using htmx to build a mobile app (Cordova/Ionic)?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, htmx

I am really interested in bringing the productivity of htmx to when I write mobile apps. Anyone have experience with using htmx in Ionic or Cordova? Any feedback from app store?

Comment: Same question here. What it takes to go from a web tech based application to run on mobile, and be approved in app stores (especially Apple's unclear stance on SPAs) is a big gap in my current understanding.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].